# A random person's GitHub link getting opened on starting my VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I start my VS Code (no matter what folder I open) the below link gets opened twice in my browser.

https://shanalikhan.github.io/2017/02/19/Option-to-ignore-settings-folders-code-settings-sync.html

I don't know the owner of this GitHub and I don't remember what led to this event. Any idea how to reverse my activity or how to prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all extensions?

Comment: I have a lot of extensions installed. I Will check if I can relate any with the problem

Comment: There is a "Start extension bisect" command, it might help.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. "Settings sync" was causing it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the extension causing this is "Setting sync", you can disable it in VS code, inside extensions.

Here is the page of the extension, that match the owner of that github user: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

Answer (score 0):

First you need to uninstall "setting sync" extension, then if you want you can re-install it again or dont need to do that cause we already have default setting sync in file > preferences > turn On setting sync Github

Answer (score 0):

I  uninstalled "setting sync" and it worked for me. I was no longer getting that  message.